Python Tkinter GIFs Overlapping
I am using tkinter to create a project. It runs fine, until f9 is pressed of which multiple instances of a gif sometimes overlap themself. I have no idea why this is happening, I have tried different logic systems, researched and asked ChatGPT. All of these solutions did not work. I have shortened the code as much as possible (so currently it is not that practical) but the code is all that is relevant to this issue.
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)  # Remove window border
root.attributes('-topmost', True)  # Keep window on top
root.attributes('-transparentcolor', 'white')  # Make white background transparent

# Define file paths
file_path_one = r'C:\Users\user\drive\Desktop\photo.png'
file_path_two = r'C:\Users\user\drive\Desktop\gif.gif'

# Load and scale the original image
image_one = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path_one).resize((200, 128), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS))

# Load GIF frames
frames_two = []
gif_two = Image.open(file_path_two)
try:
    while True:
        frames_two.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(gif_two.copy().resize((200, 128), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)))
        gif_two.seek(len(frames_two))
except EOFError:
    pass  # End of GIF frames

# Control flags
play = False
play1 = False

# Function to display the original image
def show_image_one():
    label.config(image=image_one)

# Function to trigger animation
def random_event_trigger():
    global play, play1
    if not play:
        root.after(6000, random_event_trigger)  # Wait for 6 seconds
        if not play1:
            animate_gif_loop(frames_two, repeat_count=2)

# Function to animate the GIF
def animate_gif_loop(frames, frame_index=0, repeat_count=2):
    if not play:  # Only animate if play is false
        label.config(image=frames[frame_index])
        if frame_index < len(frames) - 1:
            root.after(100, animate_gif_loop, frames, frame_index + 1, repeat_count)
        else:
            if repeat_count > 1:
                root.after(100, animate_gif_loop, frames, 0, repeat_count - 1)
            else:
                show_image_one()  # Reset to original image

# Function to handle F9 key press
def move_mouse_to_image():
    global play, play1
    play = True  # Stop animations
    play1 = True  # Stop random events
    show_image_one()  # Show the original image
    root.after(2000, reset_flags)  # Wait before resetting flags

# Reset play flags
def reset_flags():
    global play, play1
    play = False
    play1 = False
    random_event_trigger()  # Restart the random event trigger

# Create a label to display the image
label = tk.Label(root, bg='white')
label.pack()

# Position the window at the bottom-right corner
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = screen_width - 200 - 200  # Set offset
y = screen_height - 128 - 100  # Set offset
root.geometry(f'200x128+{x}+{y}')  # Set window size and position

# Start by displaying the original image and the random event trigger loop
show_image_one()
random_event_trigger()

# Bind F9 key to trigger mouse movement
root.bind('<F9>', lambda event: move_mouse_to_image())

# Run the tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()

Above is the code that I have shortened, I do not understand why the gifs overlap. My desired outcome is to have it so that only one instance of the gif animation playing exists at once.
Here is a representation of my desired outcome:
(
wait 6 seconds
idle animation plays
)
loops until f9 pressed
f9 function executes (approximately 4 seconds time)
goes back to the loop
What is happening is that after I press f9 and the function executes, I believe two loops start playing? I'm not sure but I believe this is the problem. I have no idea why two or more are playing, but the overlapping of gifs is linked to the f9 press.
It may be worth replacing the file paths with a photo and a gif of your own, for me the gif animation is choppy and overlaps when f9 is pressed.

Your code works with no overlaps. I don't get F9. Using Python 3.12.7, Wins 10. I do not see two loop starting playing.

Do you mean press F5 to start to execute instead of F9?
